# Reproduce a kind of comb border with CSS

Tags: html, css

How to reproduce that kind of border with CSS ? Only on the right side of the button. Searched everywhere without luck.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried border image? Or if it's constant - just huge list of elements for each tick

Comment: I'm not skilled enough in CSS to try that unfortunately.

Comment: Have you at least tried? Border image is old, very well supported and very well documented here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image - so before just giving up, we'd like you to at least try and ask when you get stuck on something?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll do my best to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an after pseudo element which has a repeating background linear-gradient rather than make it a true border.

This snippet puts it over the actual button, but you could put it immediately afterwards, changing the coloring.

```html
<style>
  body {
    background-color: black;
  }
  
  button {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: gold;
    position: relative;
    border-color: gold;
    border-radius: 25% 0 0 0;
    border-width: 0;
  }
  
  button::after {
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(black 0 5px, transparent 5px 10px);
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-size: 10% 10px;
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    left: 100%;
  }
</style>
<button>button</button>
```

Comment: If you remove the transform and change the black with gold you will have transparency.

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes, I didn’t know whether they wanted it to be outside or in the basic button.

Answer (score 1):

One `conic-gradient` can do the job

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  background: 
    conic-gradient(at calc(100% - 25px),#0000 25%,gold 0)
    0 0/100% 20px;
 /* 25px control the horizontal size and 20px the vertical one */
}


body {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```